# getArguments returning null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, bundle

I want to send data from my activity to my fragment. What I'm doing now is the following.

```
String itemDescription = workAssignmentItem.getDescription();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("itemDescription", itemDescription);
FirstFragment.newInstance(bundle);
```

Then in my Fragment I do:

```
public static FirstFragment newInstance(Bundle bundle) {
    FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}
```

However, when I try to do 'getArguments().getString("itemDescription");'in my onCreate, as so:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    description = getArguments().getString("itemDescription");

}
```

it will not work. getArguments returns null. I'm not quite sure why it returns null, since multiple sources on the internet say this is the way to do it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you performing a Fragment transaction to display the Fragment and after creating the Fragment instance, or is the Fragment already visible? If so the set the arguments by getting the Fragment instance from the FragmentManager

Comment: i answer this question.please accept my answer if its works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need bundle to pass a single string in Fragment

```
String itemDescription = workAssignmentItem.getDescription();
FirstFragment.newInstance(itemDescription);
```

Fragment Change to like this :

```
public static FirstFragment newInstance(String itemDescription){
    FirstFragment fragment=new FirstFragment();
    bundle args=new Bundle();
    args.putString("itemDescription",itemDescription);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

and onCreate like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    description = getArguments().getString("itemDescription");
}
```

Comment: Putting a Bundle in a Bundle, would that help?

Comment: @MarkKeen yes!!its works,but he choose a wrong way actually. he passed a bundle through fragment.it's better to pass a string.

Comment: Your comment doesn't make sense and contradicts your answer.

Comment: Other than changing the method parameter that's no different, you are still placing a string in a Bundle and setting the arguments for the Fragment.

Comment: @MarkKeen [This approach is also documented in the android developer reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out a link ... It still doesn't change what I said - your code has the exact same outcome as the OP code, as in, something else is wrong as the code supplied by OP works!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132727/discussion-between-anjal-saneen-and-mark-keen).

Answer (score 0):

So actually i had this problem

> "Bundle NULL"

I resolve it by implementing the method onFragmentResult.

***Context** : I want to pass my selected contact inside a fragment into a spinner inside an another fragment*

Where i pass my data into the Bundle :

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.item_done) {
            // Create a String array to store the names of the selected contacts
            ArrayList<String> selectedContacts = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i=0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) {
                if (listView.isItemChecked(i)) {
                    selectedContacts.add(listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                }
            }
            
            // Add the String array to the bundle
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putStringArrayList("SELECTED_CONTACTS", selectedContacts);
            Log.d("ContactsFragment", "Setting result with selectedContacts: " + selectedContacts);
            getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResult("SELECTED_CONTACTS", bundle);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and here is where i retreive my data :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sender, container, false);

    // Find the spinner views in the layout and set their adapters
    responsesSpinner = view.findViewById(R.id.responses_spinner);
    contactsSpinner = view.findViewById(R.id.contacts_spinner);

    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("SELECTED_CONTACTS", this, new FragmentResultListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle bundle) {

                    if (requestKey.equals("SELECTED_CONTACTS")) {
                        ArrayList<String> selectedContacts = bundle.getStringArrayList("SELECTED_CONTACTS");
                        Log.d("SenderFragment", "Received selectedContacts: " + selectedContacts);

                        if (selectedContacts != null && selectedContacts.size() > 0) {
                            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, selectedContacts);
                            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            contactsSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "not working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

    return view;
}
```